# Where would I save image from flash card into guest 0S( Ubuntu) and copy that saved image into new flash drives?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, dd, usb-flash-drive

**Objective:** To take image from embedded system into my development machine and save it. Use the save image to copy it into other flash drives.

My development machine has Windows 7 and guest OS is Ubuntu.

I have taken out the flash drive from embedded system and connect it to card reader.  The Guest OS (Ubuntu) has successfully detected the flash drive as /dev/sdb1.

**Question:** Where would I save this image from flash drive in my Ubuntu( guest oS) without disturbing other setting and use this image in future to upload it in other flash cards.

I am bit aware of dd command.In `dd` command `if = /dev/sdb1` but what wil i give for `if=?`  and How many bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to save image in your system.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/home/your_dir/flash.img bs=4096 conv=sync,noerror
```

The image will stored in your `/home/your_dir`

To restore it on new  flash drive, use this

```
dd if=flash.img of=/dev/sdb1
```